# How to show 2 destination waypoints when entering an origin and destination address, and the waypoint will be optional

Tags: javascript, google-maps, laravel-5, google-maps-api-3

The waypoints direction are working well, I just need to show the directions when we just put a origin address and destination1 address and the destination2 will be an optional.

I'm having a problem that the waypoints direction will only be shown when we put a origin, destination1, and also destination2 address.
is there any solution??

```
    function AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map) {
  this.map = map;
  this.originPlaceId = null;
  this.destinationPlaceId = null;
  this.destinationPlaceId2 = null;

  this.travelMode = 'DRIVING';
  this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  this.directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  this.directionsRenderer.setMap(map);

  var originInput = document.getElementById('start');
  var destinationInput = document.getElementById('waypoints');
  var destinationInput2 = document.getElementById('end');

  //var modeSelector = document.getElementById('mode-selector');

  var originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(originInput);
  // Specify just the place data fields that you need.
  originAutocomplete.setFields(['place_id']);

  var destinationAutocomplete2 =
      new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destinationInput);
      destinationAutocomplete2.setFields(['place_id']);

      var destinationAutocomplete =
      new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destinationInput2);
  // Specify just the place data fields that you need.
  destinationAutocomplete.setFields(['place_id']);




  this.setupPlaceChangedListener(originAutocomplete, 'ORIG');
  this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete, 'DEST');
  this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete2, 'DEST2');

}

AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupPlaceChangedListener = function(
    autocomplete, mode) {
  var me = this;
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);


  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    if (!place.place_id) {
      window.alert('Please select an option from the dropdown list.');
      return;
    }
    if (mode === 'ORIG') {
      me.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
    } else if (mode === 'DEST'){
      me.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
    }
     else if(mode=== 'DEST2'){
        me.destinationPlaceId2 = place.place_id;
     }


    me.route();
  });
};

AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.route = function() {
  if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId2) {
    return;
  }
  var me = this;

    var waypts = [];
  var checkboxArray = document.getElementsByClassName('waypoints');
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) {
    var address = checkboxArray[i].value;
    if (address !== '') {
      waypts.push({
        location: address,
        stopover: true
      });
    }
  }

  this.directionsService.route(
      {
        origin: {'placeId': this.originPlaceId},
        destination: {'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId},
        waypoints: waypts,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: this.travelMode
      },
      function(response, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          me.directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);

// For each route, display summary information.
      for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
        var routeSegment = i + 1;
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Route Segment: ' + routeSegment +
            '</b><br>';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
      }


        } else {
          window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
      });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the line that forces all three entries before generating the route:

```
if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId2) {
  return;
}
```

Change that to something like:

```
if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {
  return;
}
```

Then it will route with only two inputs.

Then to optionally add the waypoint:

```
var waypts = [];
if (!!this.destinationPlaceId2) {
  waypts.push({
    location: {
      'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId2
    },
    stopover: true
  });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/2oqzj3sb/)

**two entries:**
[image: screenshot with two entries]

**three entries:**
[image: screenshot with three entries]

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script
// src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    mapTypeControl: false,
    center: {
      lat: -33.8688,
      lng: 151.2195
    },
    zoom: 13
  });

  new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);
}

/**
 * @constructor
 */
function AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map) {
  this.map = map;
  this.originPlaceId = null;
  this.destinationPlaceId = null;
  this.destinationPlaceId2 = null;

  this.travelMode = 'DRIVING';
  this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  this.directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  this.directionsRenderer.setMap(map);

  var originInput = document.getElementById('start');
  var destinationInput = document.getElementById('waypoints');
  var destinationInput2 = document.getElementById('end');

  //var modeSelector = document.getElementById('mode-selector');

  var originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(originInput);
  // Specify just the place data fields that you need.
  originAutocomplete.setFields(['place_id']);

  var destinationAutocomplete2 =
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destinationInput);
  destinationAutocomplete2.setFields(['place_id']);

  var destinationAutocomplete =
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destinationInput2);
  // Specify just the place data fields that you need.
  destinationAutocomplete.setFields(['place_id']);

  this.setupPlaceChangedListener(originAutocomplete, 'ORIG');
  this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete, 'DEST');
  this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete2, 'DEST2');

}

AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupPlaceChangedListener = function(
  autocomplete, mode) {
  var me = this;
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);


  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    if (!place.place_id) {
      window.alert('Please select an option from the dropdown list.');
      return;
    }
    if (mode === 'ORIG') {
      me.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
    } else if (mode === 'DEST') {
      me.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
    } else if (mode === 'DEST2') {
      me.destinationPlaceId2 = place.place_id;
    }
    me.route();
  });
};

AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.route = function() {
  console.log("originPlaceId=" + this.originPlaceId + " destinationPlaceId=" + this.destinationPlaceId + " destinationPlaceId2=" + this.destinationPlaceId2)
  if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {
    return;
  }

  var me = this;

  var waypts = [];
  if (!!this.destinationPlaceId2) {
    waypts.push({
      location: {
        'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId2
      },
      stopover: true
    });
  }

  this.directionsService.route({
      origin: {
        'placeId': this.originPlaceId
      },
      destination: {
        'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId
      },
      waypoints: waypts,
      optimizeWaypoints: true,
      travelMode: this.travelMode
    },
    function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        me.directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
        var route = response.route[0];
        // For each route, display summary information.
        for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
          var routeSegment = i + 1;
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Route Segment: ' + routeSegment +
            '</b><br>';
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
        }


      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
};
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 70%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#start,
#waypoints,
#end {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 200px;
}

#start:focus,
#waypoints:focus,
#end:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#mode-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}

#mode-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="start" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter an origin location">

  <input id="end" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a destination location">

  <input id="waypoints" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a destination location">

  <div id="mode-selector" class="controls">
    <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-walking" checked="checked">
    <label for="changemode-walking">Walking</label>

    <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-transit">
    <label for="changemode-transit">Transit</label>

    <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-driving">
    <label for="changemode-driving">Driving</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```